# How to get Unicode string when using request.querystring['param']

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, unicode

How do I get a Unicode `string` when using `request.querystring['param']`

Comment: In C#, strings are in Unicode by default. You need to be more specific about what problem you're having.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is not any problem with using `Request.QueryString["param"]` for Unicode `string`s.

Though, you can declare `Request` and `Response` encoding in `web.config` like this (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkak5b9%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)):

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization
       requestEncoding="utf-8"
       responseEncoding="utf-8"
      />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```